# Async vs Horizontal scaling

Tags: asp.net, rest, asynchronous, parallel-processing, horizontal-scaling

I am working on a .net client which consumes a REST api (JSON). The client is a web application with high traffic and considerable user interaction

When writing the wrappers around the external REST api i am trying to decide

1. If i should make all calls made for the API async? This will be all the way from UI to the API as explained here http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html. This will help me in achieving the desired performance  but i will have to figure out a way to handle UI when Tasks are waiting to be completed
2. Or Is it an overkill? And do i just use sync/sequential  code? I could still get (some) performance  by Horizontally scaling the application?

I am keen to understand what is the preferred way of calling an external REST api from a client (if there is any) and how is the UI handled for those case where people do use async?

Comment: How many requests will there be running at the same time? Or, how many requests per second will you need to serve and how long will they take?

Comment: During the busiest period (a sale), typical load would be like 2700 unique requests per 5 min or around 500 per min. At any given point during that sale, we expect 170 concurrent users online.
As to how long they take, its basically an inventory page, where users will see the most updated inventory so its just a database read operation over the API, the records returned will be in the region of 150 per call. Sorry, if this doesnt answer your question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have about 10 requests per second in a busy period. This by itself does not require asynchronous IO. Assuming 1sec per request that's 10 threads. 10 threads are *nothing*.

There is one special case, though: What if the backend service you are calling sometimes takes a long time to respond (a bug, overload, index rebuild, ...)? If it takes 30 seconds to respond or timeout that means that 300 requests are in flight. This is too much for the default thread-pool settings. This will effectively shut down the entire app by pool exhaustion until the requests are cleared.

You can do two things:

1. Use async IO for all high-volume actions.
2. Reduce timeouts and have a load-breaker for the number of in-flight requests. Example:

.

```
SemaphoreSlim sem = new SS(50); //max 50 in-flight

//...

if (!sem.WaitOne(TimeSpan.Zero))
 throw new Exception("Load limit exceeded");
```

Both are equally safe and well-performing. Do not make the mistake to think that async IO causes your IOs to become faster.

The semaphore solution requires less architectural changes but it requires permission to drop requests. These requests would not have completed anyway with high likelihood.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Makes sense. I do have a circuit breaker implementation on top of this API call, timeout and threshold of which we configure during onload to a sensible number. Any thoughts on how to handle UI while i wait for requests to finish? What strategy if any i could use? Say a user applies a few filters on the inventory page, and part of the workflow is that the filters are applied on the latest dataset. In these scenarios, how do i handle async calls?

Comment: I don't see the particular problem you are having. Why does the UI need special handling in case of overload? Show an error.